# Help needed on computing $\sum_n \frac{1}{n^4}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

I am trying to compute $\sum_{n \geq 1} 1/n^4$ using Fourier series.

I am considering the $2\pi$ periodic function $f(x)=x^2$ on
$(-\pi,\pi)$. I computed the following :

$c_0(f)=\frac{\pi^2}{3}$, $c_n(f)=\frac{2 (-1)^n}{n^2}$ if $n \neq 0$.

Moreover, $\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |f^2(x)| dx = \frac{\pi^4}{5}$.

Now applying the Parseval identity to $f$, I find 
$\sum_{n \geq 1} 1/n^4 = \frac{\pi^4}{40} - \frac{\pi^2}{24}$.

But this can't be right, because apparently the sum I am looking for is 
$\frac{\pi^4}{90}$.

Where did I go wrong ? I don't understand how you can not get a $\pi^2$ term from $|c_0|^2$ in the Parseval identity.

Comment: $c_0 = \frac{\pi^2}{3}$, so $c_0^2 = \frac{\pi^4}{9}$.

Comment: thanks ! I can't believe I got confused over this...